# Get the running unique count of items till a give date, similar to running total but instead a running unique count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with user shopping data as shown below

[image]

I want an output similar to running total but instead I want the running total of the count of unique categories that the user has shopped for by date.

[image]

I know I have to make use of `ROWS PRECEDING AND FOLLOWING` in the `count` function but I am not able to user `count(distinct category)` in a window function

```
Dt  category    userId
4/10/2022   Grocery 123
4/11/2022   Grocery 123
4/12/2022   MISC    123
4/13/2022   SERVICES    123
4/14/2022   RETAIl  123
4/15/2022   TRANSP  123
4/20/2022   GROCERY 123
```

Desired output

```
Dt  userID  number of unique categories
4/10/2022   123 1
4/11/2022   123 1
4/12/2022   123 2
4/13/2022   123 3
4/14/2022   123 4
4/15/2022   123 5
4/20/2022   123 5
```

Comment: please replace images with plain text so we can help you then

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Added the text at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select Dt, userId, 
  ( select count(distinct category)
    from t.categories as category
  ) number_of_unique_categories
from (
select *, array_agg(lower(category)) over(partition by userId order by Dt) categories
from your_table
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]